# Empty DIV pushes down content in table-cell next to it

Tags: html, css

I'm getting some strange CSS behavior when using display:table,table-row,table-cell

When a table-cell contains an empty div, it pushes down the content of the cell next to it.

```
<html>
  <body>

    <div style="height:200px">
      <div style="display:table">
        <div style="display:table-row">
          <div style="display:table-cell">
            <div style="height:100px;width:200px;overflow-y:scroll"></div>
          </div>
          <div style="display:table-cell">
            <div style="height:100px;width:100px;overflow-y:scroll">Why am I getting pushed down?!?</div>  
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div style="height:200px">
      <div style="display:table">
        <div style="display:table-row">
          <div style="display:table-cell">
            <div style="height:100px;width:200px;overflow-y:scroll">A</div>
          </div>
          <div style="display:table-cell">
            <div style="height:100px;width:100px;overflow-y:scroll">Suddenly I'm not getting pushed down?!?</div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

If I put some content in the DIV, behavior stops. Is this a bug? Affects Firefox and Chrome. If it's not a bug, how do I get around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get around this problem, set `vertical-align:top` on the empty td.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5myvyk/2/)**

Comment: Still think it looks like a bug tho :P

Comment: The default value for `vertical:align` is `baseline` so I don't think it's a bug

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers can use different systems it is hard to say that if this is a bug or your browser
acting differently or could be a server not updating to check this inspect element and check if code matches